# SNMP : cisco GigabitEthernet interface unreachable?

Tags: perl, switch-statement, snmp, cisco, oid

I can not request GigabitEthernet interfaces on a cisco switch 2960.
When I execute :

```
use Net::SNMP;
use Net::SNMP::Interfaces;
my $interfaces = Net::SNMP::Interfaces->new(Hostname => $hostname, Community => $community);
    my @inter = $interfaces->all_interfaces();

    my $it;

    for my $i (@inter) {
        my $it = $i->ifDescr();
        print $i->name()."\n";
    }
```

I get the output :

FastEthernet0/1
FastEthernet0/2
FastEthernet0/3
...
FastEthernet0/23
FastEthernet0/24
GigabitEthernet0/1
GigabitEthernet0/2

---

So, up to now, everything's ok.

I get the ifIndex of a GigabitEthernet interface (ex. GigabitEthernet0/2) :

```
my $in = $interfaces->interface("GigabitEthernet0/2");
print "INDEX:".$in->index()."\n";
```

It returns :

```
INDEX:10102
```

So, I know the ifIndex of my interface.
But I need to get the VLAN too, to get informations about speed, alias, duplex, mac address connected to this interface....

Here start the problems :

```
#Listing all VLANS
my $vmVlan = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2";
my $vlans = SnmpUtil->new($hostname, $community);
my %vl = $vlans->requeteTable($vmVlan);
foreach my $k (keys(%vl)) {
   print "Clef=$k Valeur=$vl{$k}\n";
}
```

It displays :
...
Clef=10013 Valeur=1
Clef=10011 Valeur=1
Clef=10014 Valeur=1
Clef=10002 Valeur=10
...

But ifIndex of GigabitEthernet0/2 (10102) is not in this hash...
So I can not find the VLAN.
How to get all infos of GigabitEthernet interface ? Other solution ?
Need some help, big reward !

---

*EDIT* :
Solution found, GigabitEhernet ports seem to be on VLAN 1, even if they don't appear in lising vlan.

Answer (score 0):

If those interfaces are in trunk mode, you won't see them with that OID.  CISCO-VLAN-MEMBERSHIP-MIB is only for non-trunking ports.

You can try vlanTrunkPortDynamicStatus from CISCO-VTP-MIB to check.